# Angular js code not getting called, any thing wrong with syntax

Tags: angularjs

Below is the code i am calling on a factory controler but below code is not working, is there any thing wrong with syntax?

```
<script>
        EposApp.factory('getCustomization', function () {
            return
            {
                customization: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model))
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it like this (remove new line after return),

```
  EposApp.factory('getCustomization', function () {
                return {
                    customization: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))
                }
            });
```

In javascript it does the [semicolon insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi) , therefore it will take `return` as a valied statement and your function will return `undefined`

Comment: no it doesnt work still there is some it is showing in the syntax.

Comment: Are you getting a syntax error in the browser console ?

Comment: ah you need to remove `@` before the `Model`

Comment: Yeah , but you have put `@` at the beginning of the statement, and then you don't have to put it again before Model, since the statement is not ended.